# How to add a custom Windows audio input?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device that streams audio through a custom service, and need to be able to use it in any Windows application (e.g. stream the audio to Skype or Google Chrome for example). I believe the only way is to make this audio source appear as a standard Windows audio input, but how to do this ?

I think the most reliable way to interract with a BLE device is through UWP (using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice), so I used it to get the audio data. Then, I used the Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraph to interract with the audio system. I'm able to generate the Windows audio stream from the BLE audio data with the AudioFrameInputNode and output it to my application default output with AudioDeviceOutputNode.

I can't override the default system audio input and audio output (e.g the laptop microphone and speakers) so in order to be able to use the output from my application as an input in other application, I used VB-Audio (https://www.vb-audio.com/) combined with the "App volume and device preferences" Windows feature. This way, I can use the VB-Audio Cable to connect the output of my application to the input of another, without having to set them as default system devices.

In theory, this should do what I need to do, but in fact, this setup isn't reliable.

I don't understand why, but the behavior isn't consistent at all. Most of the time, changing the audio settings (from "App volume and device preferences" and the "Audio devices panel") have no effect. With the same settings, sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't (audio from my application is played on speaker instead of VB-Cable input, etc.)...

I don't know where the problem comes from, VB-Audio or Windows itself ? Is there a more reliable alternative to this setup ?

Otherwise, is there another way to use a custom audio source from an application like a standard Windows audio input ?

Please let me know if anything is unclear or you need any more information.

**EDIT:**
I think [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1348988/set-audio-endpoint-devices-application-specific-programmatically) is actually about the same issue that I'm facing.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for more diagnosis.

Comment: The setup can be reproduced using [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/win10-1511/Samples/AudioCreation) from UWP with the FrameInput Node scenario. This was my starting point to implement the audio part of my application.

Comment: Please provide the whole steps to reproduce your issue by using the 'AudioGraph sample/FrameInput Node scenario' sample. Step by step.

Comment: - Install VB-Audio
- Start the FrameInput Node scenario from the AudioGraph sample
- In the "App volume and device preferences", set the default output for the AudioGraph sample to VB-Cable input
- In the "App volume and device preferences", set the default input of any recording application (VLC Media Player or Audacity for example) as VB-Cable output